# Not login to system due to changing permission

Tags: linux

I am using Linux system but by mistake I fired a chmod command as follows:-

chmod -R 777 /

after that I restart my System. But when I try to login, the system is login but after 2-3 seconds again to login window. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Wrongly set chmod / 777. Problems?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12998/43400)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just get your important files and configs backup them. format the partition which the OS installed, then reinstall again, sorry there is no easy way to correct these permissions.